# Sanitize a string in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Hi I've got follow code

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input ng-model="value">
  <button ng-click="checkValue()">Check value</button>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.value = '';

  $scope.acceptedValuesList = {
    "Items": [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'MI'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'MO'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'AB'
    }]
  };

  $scope.checkValue = function() {
    if (acceptedValuesList.Items.find((item) => item.text == $scope.value)) {
      console.log("accepted value");
    } else {
      // SANITIZE VALUE UNTIL IT'S CORRECT
    }
  }
});
```

When I write one of the string, which are in my array ('MI', 'MO' or 'AB') in the input and click on the button, it searches for the string in my list and if the value in the input matches with one of the three string, I print a little message in my console. This works fine. So know I would like to sanitize my value in the input, if there is also another letter. For example, when I wirte "ABx" into the input and press the button, it should remove the "x" and show "AB" in the input. How can I do this? I didn't find anything, that could help me. I hope this is clear enough. Thanks.

**EDIT: MY OWN SOLUTION:**

This is my solution: I write a value in my input field: input value = xy**Ab**s;

First of all I use `toUpperCase()` to ignore case sensitive.

Than I loop throught my list with `find()` and search for my value in the current looped item.

```
$scope.value.toUpperCase(); // $scope.value = 'XYABS'

let item = $scope.acceptedValuesList.Items.find((item: any) => $scope.value.search(item.name) >= 0); // item = object in the list with id = 3 and name = 'AB'
```

After that, I check if there was an item found, so my value in the input is in one of my items in my list. Than I use `substr()` to get the substring in the value from the position where it starts with the length of the name.  After that I get my string. If there was no item found, so my string is wrong, I clear the input:

```
if(item) {
    $scope.value = $scope.value.substr($scope.value.search(item.name), item.name.length); // $scope.value = 'AB'
} else {
    $scope.value = '';
}
```

This works fine for me, I hope it's clear enough. Thanks. :)

Comment: What if you have a string like QUWFHUI**MO**X  ? Or, even better: What if you have a string like UQHFU**MI**ASD**MO**?

Comment: @Xatenev Hi, I didn't explained it very well, it should be possible to type anything else then this three strings, so when you press 'M' or 'A' on your keyboard, it will put it into the input. After that, when you press 'I', 'O' or 'B', it also should put it into the input, but when you type any other key it shouldn't put it into the input, also when the first letter is a wrong...

Comment: @Xatenev So when you type "MIX" it should be "MI" in the input. When you type "MOR" it should be "MO" in the input. When you type "ABC", it should be "AB" in the input. And when you type "WRABC", the first to letter should be ignored, than "AB" should be in the input an the last letter "C" also should be ignored and than when you have a count of 2 letters in the input, it shouldn't be possible to type again, so "MO" should also be ignored...

Comment: `if(string.search("MI") { console.log("ITS MI"); } else if(string.search("MO") { console.log("ITS MO"); } `

Comment: @Xatenev Hi please look at my edited question, I found my own solution which works fine and I think it's a nice one... Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use watch and compare the values

```
$scope.$watch('value', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  var newText;
  if(newVal.indexOf("MI") > 0) {
     newText = "MI"; 
  } else if(newVal.indexOf("MO") > 0) {
     newText = "MO"; 
  } else if(newVal.indexOf("AB") > 0) {
     newText = "AB";  
  }
  $scope.value = newText;
});
```

Comment: Hi, look please at my edited question. I found my own solution. Thanks again.

Comment: yeah, that's pretty simple